# launch basic bash script on docker build from windows system

Tags: windows, bash, docker, dockerfile

I would like to construct a docker image based from script bash for provisioning my system.

I try to build my image and docker tell me **"Successfully built"** but when I try to launch this I can see this message : **"No such file or directory"** and I can't viewing container in ***Kitematic*** application.

If I launch docker inspect on my container (created correctly but not launched) I can view a **ExitCode 127**.

Can you help me to understand issue and also help me to launch correctly a simple script bash for provisionning image docker.

**dockerfile :**

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER barbie rambo <barbierambo@mymail.com>

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk wget openssh-server tar vim

COPY scripts/base.sh /home/docker/scripts/base.sh
RUN chmod 744 /home/docker/scripts/base.sh
ENTRYPOINT /home/docker/scripts/base.sh
```

**my base.sh script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Set non-interactive mode
#export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update the box
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev
apt-get -y install curl unzip
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
apt-get -y install gnupg2

# others tools
sudo apt-get -y install nano
sudo apt-get -y install vim
sudo apt-get -y install aptitude
sudo apt-get -y install git
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt-get -y install whois
sudo apt-get -y install dos2unix
```

Comment: Do you really want this also as an `ENTRYPOINT`? How do you start the image?

Comment: I don't really want ENTRYPOINT I just want provisionning my image with script. I start my image with docker run.

Comment: Hmmm, I ran your code and it worked. But I'd switch `ENTRYPOINT` with `RUN` to really build the image and not run the installation for every `docker run` - you might also check if you're overwriting an existing entrypoint. Spaces like in VladoDemcak's answer might also be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether `/home/docker/scripts/base.sh` has EOL as UNIX/OSX Format, if not you can do EOL Conversion in Notepad++

- open file in `Notepad++ -> Edit -> EOL Conversion -> UNIX/OSX Format -> Save`
- then rebuild docker image

If you want to get into container ten run following:

`docker ps -a`

and use container id
`docker exec -i -t [containerID] bash`

and check whether file `/home/docker/scripts/base.sh` exists

Comment: I confirm that docker build run correctly but I don't understand why docker run launch my script and exit code 0 without launch container.

Comment: It is because docker just executed `base.sh` (ENTRYPOINT service) with your installs and exited. Nothing else. You need to run bash in "foreground" or something else (just not in deamon mode) to keep docker container alive.

Comment: @darkomen The problem "No such file or directory" was with EOL?